# How to save data from gridcontrol devexpress into oracle database?

Tags: c#, oracle, devexpress

I have a `GridControl` data that I inserted form `TextEdit` in C#, then I want save those data to oracle database, this my scenario:

```
private void fmTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("NAMA");
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("ALAMAT");
    dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

This my method to save data from `TextEdit` to `Grid`:

```
public void SimpanGrid()
{
    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    dr1[0] = txtNama.Text;
    dr1[1] = txtAlamat.Text;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

This methode to save data from `GridControl` but I got still error:

```
public void SimpanTest()
{
    //membuat koneksi_manual
    if (koneksi_manual.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        koneksi_manual.con.Close();
    }
    koneksi_manual.con.Open();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TEST (NAMA, ALAMAT) 
                    VALUES ('" + gridView1.Columns[i].FieldName.ToString() +
                          "', '" + gridView1.Columns[i].FieldName.ToString() + "')";

            cmd.Connection = koneksi_manual.con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //eror disini
            MessageBox.Show("DATA TELAH DISIMPAN");
            koneksi_manual.con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Memunculkan pesan error
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Then I call that method `SimpanTes()` in `Button Simpan`:

```
private void btnSimpan_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SimpanTest();
}
```

So, this the problem I couldn't save data to database and I don't know what the correct code must I use.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TEST (NAMA, ALAMAT) 
                            VALUES ('" + gridView1.Columns[i].FieldName.ToString() +
                                  "', '" + gridView1.Columns[i].FieldName.ToString() + "')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. You are closing the connection at the end of your cycle and in the next iteration your getting the error with closed connection. So, you must open your connection before execution of command. Also you need to use [`GridView.DataRowCount`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_DataRowCounttopic) property instead of [`GridView.RowCount`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCounttopic) because `GridView.RowCount` counts visible rows, group rows, new row and filter row. And to get the row cell value you must use [`GridView.GetRowCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowCellValuetopic1517) method.
Here is example:

```
if (koneksi_manual.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)    
   koneksi_manual.con.Close();

for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount - 1; i++)// <= Use gridView1.DataRowCount instead of gridView1.RowCount.
{    
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TEST (NAMA, ALAMAT) 
            VALUES ('" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "NAMA") +
                  "', '" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "ALAMAT") + "')";// <= Use gridView1.GetRowCellValue to get the cell value.

    cmd.Connection = koneksi_manual.con;

    koneksi_manual.con.Open();// <= Open connection before executing the command.

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //eror disini
    MessageBox.Show("DATA TELAH DISIMPAN");
    koneksi_manual.con.Close();
}
```

But also you can use your `dt` object directly to save values from it:

```
if (koneksi_manual.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)    
   koneksi_manual.con.Close();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
{    
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TEST (NAMA, ALAMAT) 
            VALUES ('" + dataRow["NAMA"] +
                  "', '" + dataRow["ALAMAT"] + "')";

    cmd.Connection = koneksi_manual.con;

    koneksi_manual.con.Open();// <= Open connection before executing the command.

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //eror disini
    MessageBox.Show("DATA TELAH DISIMPAN");
    koneksi_manual.con.Close();
}
```